# Force SharePoint InfoPath content type to open through browser, not pop out InfoPath

Tags: infopath, forms-services, forms-library

When I:

create a form in InfoPath designer
publish it as a new content type to my FormTemplates folder
Go into my Forms Library and add from existing content types this content type
It allows me to create a new form and save it in the browser.

If I:

create a form in InfoPath designer
create a new content type
give it the form as the template
Go into my Forms Library and add from existing content types this content type
It tries to create the new form through an InfoPath popout.

I cannot find the setting that I need to apply to my content type so i can use method two. (My req is for it to be handled through the browser.) I know there is Form Library Settings > Advanced Settings > Open Documents in the Browser > Open in the browser as the default behavior. But this does not affect my form.

I can create two different content types using these two methods and apply them to the same forms library, and one will create in the browser and one as an InfoPath popout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know there is Form Library Settings > Advanced Settings > Open
>   Documents in the Browser > Open in the browser as the default
>   behavior. But this does not affect my form

There are 2 places for configuring this. One is that you mentioned and another is in 
InfoPath Forms Services setting (using the Farm Administrators Sharepoint Group user):

- Sharepoint Central Administration > **General Application Settings** > Configure Infopath Forms Services > under the User **Browser-enabled Form Templates** category, check **Render form templates that are browser-enabled by users**

Also, irrespective of these settings the Infopath form will be opened in Filler/client:

- if the used for opening an Infopath form browser [is not compatible with Sharepoint server IPFS](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/web-browser-compatibility-in-infopath-forms-services-HA010204085.aspx#BM1) (Infopath Forms Services). The link does not provide the full list of problematic browsers (IMO, 64 bit Internet Explorers and IE 8 fail to open browser forms in browser, etc.) + this also depends on browser's configuration settings
- if the Infopath form has features that are not [supported by IPFS](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/web-browser-compatibility-in-infopath-forms-services-HA010204085.aspx#BM2)
- if the form template was published as not web-browser enabled from Infopath Designer (Tools -> Form Options -> Compatibility)
- IPFS were not enabled on Sharepoint server
- the form is opened from within the task (like (e.g. task in Approval workflow)
- the form template was uploaded instead of being published
- etc.

The more certain solution is to open [through link with appended "?OpenIn=Browser" or "&DefaultItemOpen=1"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772417%28v=office.12%29.aspx)