# Infopath content type opens in infopath not in the browser

Tags: document-library, infopath, content-type

I have document library *helpdesk*

and I have content type named  *helpdesktemplate*.Then I allowed content types in

*helpdesk* document library.Then I added *helpdesktemplate* content type in it as

defaut.So I want to open template in browser not in infopath  when I click  "new

document".

Comment: This [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58411/force-sharepoint-infopath-content-type-to-open-through-browser-not-pop-out-info) could not help me too

Answer (score 0):

Check your configuring: one is that you mentioned and another is in InfoPath Forms Services setting (using the Farm Administrators Sharepoint Group user):

- Sharepoint Central Administration > **General Application Settings** > **Configure Infopath Forms Services** > under the User **Browser-enabled Form Templates** category, check Render form templates that are browser-enabled by users

Also, irrespective of these settings the Infopath form will be opened in Filler/client:

- if the used for opening an Infopath form browser is not compatible with Sharepoint server IPFS (Infopath Forms Services). The link does not provide the full list of problematic browsers (IMO, 64 bit Internet Explorers and IE 8 fail to open browser forms in browser, etc.) + this also depends on browser's configuration settings
- if the Infopath form has features that are not supported by IPFS
- if the form template was published as not web-browser enabled from Infopath Designer (Tools -> Form Options -> Compatibility)
- IPFS were not enabled on Sharepoint server
- the form is opened from within the task (like (e.g. task in Approval workflow)
- the form template was uploaded instead of being published
  etc.